# Populate SQL Server table column with percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table that has a column for `prices` and I have another column called `percentage`. I want to be able to auto populate the percentage column by dividing a row's price by the total price*100. Is there any way that this is possible?

Example:

```
Price    Percentage
-------------------
8.00     80%
2.00     20%
```

to get these percentage values:

```
(price in row 1 / sum of prices) * 100
(price in row 2 / sum of prices) * 100
```

Comment: It is possible, but unless your row count and the individual prices remain the same, I would not do it. Calculate it on the fly.

Comment: They wouldn't stay the same... I plan to have a form on a web side that will let a user edit the price... Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Seems you just need a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) here. I think by "rows price", they mean **row's** price, @Shadow .

Comment: @Larnu which calculates the precentage on the fly. Btw, since this calculation requires a separate query to get the sum, you would also need an UDF to get around the no subquery restriction of computed columns.

Comment: @Larnu, Sorry about that, I have edited the question

Comment: I read total price as being something else on the row, @Shadow , though I can see your interpretation too. With no sample data, we'd have to guess. Either the OP needs a calculated column if it doesn't require aggregation, or a `VIEW` if it does.

Comment: @Larnu, I have edited the question again... I hope it gives clarity

Comment: Ok, then yes, you want a `VIEW`, not a computed column here.

Comment: @Larnu I am a bit confused... would a view populate an existing percentage column in the table?

Comment: No, a `VIEW` is a different object. Don't store aggregated values in a table, it's a mistake. You'll either need to invest in `TRIGGER`s to `UPDATE` the table **every** time you do an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, or use a user-defined scalar function in a computed column, which can (read will) significantly hurt performance. A `VIEW` is a far better option here, as it doesn't have any of those problems.

Comment: Ah okay... I get you. Would that mean that there is no need for that percentage column in the table? Also would I be able to pull those percentage into a web form?